# How do I manipulate datetime (tick labels and limits) on a plot axis in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have a plot created within a for loop with a list of datetimes as the x values. The x ticks are labeled as dates, but I would like to display the hour (i.e. 6, 12, 18, 24 repeating). I would also like to set xlim to wider than the dataset so all data points are within the axes (not on the edges). I would post the figure, but this is my first question on stackoverflow, so that is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a touch confusing the first time you do it, but it's easiest to use explicit formatters and locators for this.  To keep the points from touching the boundaries, use `ax.margins(pad)` or equivalently `plt.margins(pad)`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2014', '01/05/2014', freq='1H')
y = np.random.random(dates.size)

locator = mdates.HourLocator(range(0, 24, 6))
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%H')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, y, 'ko')
ax.margins(0.05) # Keep points from touching margin of plot

ax.xaxis.set(major_formatter=formatter, major_locator=locator)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you might prefer the hours to be displayed more like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2014', '01/05/2014', freq='1H')
y = np.random.random(dates.size)

locator = mdates.HourLocator(range(0, 24, 6))
formatter = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dates, y, 'ko')
ax.margins(0.05) # Keep points from touching margin of plot

ax.xaxis.set(major_formatter=formatter, major_locator=locator)
fig.autofmt_xdate() # Quick way of rotating tick labels

plt.show()
```

[image]